# geoserver wfs insert error

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2, geoserver

I keep getting an insert error from geoserver when trying to save a point, poly etc etc to my postgis table.  any ideas, my code is below

```
    var Projection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); 

    var map = new OpenLayers.Map("Map", {
        //projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        displayProjection:Projection,
        controls:[] 
       }
    );

    //add google map
    var GoogleMap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "GoogleSatellite",{
            type:G_SATELLITE_MAP,
            isBaseLayer:true,
            sphericalMercator:true,
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34),
            numZoomLevels: 21  
        } 
    );  

    var NYC = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
      "nyc_buildings - Tiled", "http://soiisdev:8080/geoserver/wms",
        {
            layers: 'cite:nyc_buildings',
            styles: '',
            format: "image/png",
            tiled: 'true',
            transparent: true,
            Projection:Projection 
        },
        {
            buffer: 0,
            displayOutsideMaxExtent: true
        }               
   ); 

   var saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save({auto:true})

    var vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vectors", {
        strategies: [
            new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), 
            saveStrategy
        ],
        Projection:Projection, 
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            version: "1.1.0", 
            url:  "http://soiisdev:8080/geoserver/wfs",
            featureNS : "http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite", 
            featureType: "nyc_vectors",
            srsName: "EPSG:4326"
        })
    });

    map.addLayers([GoogleMap, NYC, vectors]); 
    //map.zoomToMaxExtent();

    var LonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-73.988113, 40.750898);
    LonLat.transform(Projection, map.getProjectionObject());  
    map.setCenter(LonLat, 15);
```

ive checked the header in fiddler and below is the xml sent to geoserver

```
<wfs:Transaction xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs  http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
<wfs:Insert>
 <feature:nyc_vectors xmlns:feature="http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite">
   <feature:the_geom>
     <gml:Point xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4326">
       <gml:pos>-73.986374928559 40.742379645006</gml:pos>
     </gml:Point>
   </feature:the_geom>
 </feature:nyc_vectors>
```

Comment: you should post the postgreSQL error message

Comment: I'd agree; the code looks good, so post the error, and possibly any logs.

Comment: Recent one of 2.1 RC release has issue with WFS-T and Postgis. try with latest RC5

Comment: Probably just a copy and paste mistake, but the XML is incomplete: The closing `</wfs:Transaction>` and `</wfs:insert>` are missing. Mmmh, also the `xmlns:xsi` attribute is missing a closing quote!

Answer (score 1):

You should also post the version of PostGIS and PostgreSQL you are using.

To determine that use:

SELECT postgis_full_version();
SELECT version();

Note in PostGIS 2.0 we dropped a lot of deprecated functions.  This has caused some people running GeoServer some problems.  If you are running GeoServer latest RC and PostGIS 2.0 and you are still having problems. Install the legacy.sql file packaged with PostGIS 2.0.

http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/PostGIS_FAQ.html#legacy_faq